# test class extends abstract class (Angular 5, Jasmine, Karma)

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, extends, testunit

I want to test `aclass.component.ts` but it always return errors, how can I run the test and call `Bclass` in the `Aclass.spec.ts`.

```
export class Aclass extends Bclass{
  constructor(
    private vueService: VueService,
    private projetService: ProjetService    
  ) {
    super();
  }
}
export abstract class Bclass implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
     constructor() {
        this.activatedRoute = AppInjector.get(ActivatedRoute);
        this.vueLifeCycleService = AppInjector.get(VueLifeCycleService);
    }}
```

Comment: `Bclassimplements` should have a space, `Bclass implements`

Comment: @SrAxi it's typo :D

Comment: What are you asking?  If you want a generic example of how to test an Abstract Class you can check out this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-q-54236304?file=app%2Fgen-form-input-component-base.spec.ts).

Comment: @dmcgrandle thank you this is exactly what i need